# Getting full request url - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have request to server like : `"http://localhost/Login/Index?asdhkjashdaskjdhqwehw"`.

And my `Action` :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     stringUrl = ;
     return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

I want to get string : **"asdhkjashdaskjdhqwehw"** in `Action` **Index**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. 
Using : "`HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString()`"

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect with sending additional parameter which contain your data :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     stringUrl = ;
     return RedirectToAction("Index","Home", new {data = "asdhkjashdaskjdhqwehw" });
}
```

In your Home Index action, you can get data with having argument in your action:

```
public ActionResult Index(string data) // data contains the data passed
{
     return RedirectToAction("Your URL");
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry , my question is not clear. You can check it.

Comment: You can get data in similar way by using parameter in action for your url too